# как установить толщинy одной линии drawLine

Tags: java, graphics

Есть класс

```
    `public class DrawPanel extends  JButton`
```

в нем рисую линию

```
       `@Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
        g2d.drawLine(a/2,0,a/2,a);//а-размер кнопки
    }`
```

при отображении кнопки вместе с линией становится толстой и рамка кнопки.
Как сделать толстой только линию?

Answer (score 1):

```
    `@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
    g2d.drawLine(a/2,0,a/2,a);//а-размер кнопки
    //
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));//добавил, чтобы после линии рамка отрисовывалась размером 1
    }`
```